# use static android context in static method

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-context

I have a `PrefUtils` class like this:

```java
public class PrefUtils {

    public PrefUtils() {
    }

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void storeAccessToken(Context context, String access_token) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
       editor.putString("Access_Token", access_token);
       editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getAccessToken(Context context) {
        return getSharedPreferences(context).getString("Access_Token", null);
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity` I have a static method and I should use a static Context for it :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Context mcontex;
// Is It right To Add Context To static Variable???

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_method();

}
    public static void my_method(){
        String access_token =PrefUtils.getAccessToken(mcontex);
        // more code ...
    }
}
```

Is it right to add Context to a static variable? 
Android Studio says: "Do not place Android Context class in static field".
Does this cause an error like memory leak? And if answer is Yes, what is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `Context` as a parameter to the method rather than keeping the `context` in a static variable.

```
public static void myMethod(@NonNull Context context){

        String access_token =PrefUtils.getAccessToken(context);
        // more code ...
    }
```

The downside of having a static context variable is that there is no guarantee that the non-static onCreate() will have been called before some static initialization code tries to fetch your static Context object. That means your calling code will need to be ready to deal with null values.

Comment: thanks, its good answer - i should say that i use this method in another fragment.

Comment: why not? just pass the current context to the method from anywhere.